# Change file and folder icon those are checked in in TFVC

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I see in a training video file and folder icons in file explorer was different where those are checked in in TFS. 
How he did that? 
Thanks for answers

[pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OnGhr.png)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to install the extension TFS Power Tools for Visual Studio, make sure the component `Windows Shell Extension` is installed :

- For VS 2015: [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015
  Power Tools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=TFSPowerToolsTeam.MicrosoftVisualStudioTeamFoundationServer2015Power)
- For VS 2017: [Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control Windows Shell
  Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-vcw.TfsShellExtention)

Just download the matching version accordingly if you are using the other version of VS.

**Please note that you need to restart the machine after installing the extension to get it work.**

[image]

Comment: HI. thanks Andy Li-MSFT. I installed Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2017 Power Tools but I don't see any change. Should I do some things?

Comment: @AmirHoseinsaadatmand For VS 2017 the extension is not `Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2017 Power Tools` , it 's `Microsoft Team Foundation Version Control Windows Shell Extension`, just click the link in above answer to download and install. After the installation, you need to  **restart your computer** to get it work.

Comment: @AmirHoseinsaadatmand Besides, make sure the files/folders are in source control. You need to connect to TFS, then create a workspace and map sources to local folder, then you can see the icons in the local folder with windows explorer...

Comment: @AmirHoseinsaadatmand Have you resolved the issue? any update?

Answer (score 0):

It's an extension for windows explorer, you can use this link to install it.
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2018/03/21/tfvc-windows-shell-extension-for-vsts-and-tfs-2018/